# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paddle.distributed'

Tags: ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am trying to run the following code to train paddleOCR.

```
import paddle
import paddle.distributed as dist
```

But I'm getting this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paddle.distributed'

Even after I have installed paddle-client.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the paddlepaddle with 2.3.1 version，and quick install can refer to: https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/en

Answer (score 0):

```
docker pull paddlepaddle/paddle:2.3.0-gpu-cuda11.2-cudnn8
```

I use this images which can work well.